# Observable.of turn async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, observable, rxjs5

I'm about to mock a http call wrapped into observable. My initial idea was to simply use `Observable.of` similar to `Promise.resolve`, but it does not seem to work as I expected:

```js
Rx.Observable.of('of1').subscribe(e => console.log(e));

console.log('of2');

Rx.Observable.from(Promise.resolve('from1')).subscribe(e => console.log(e));

console.log('from2');
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

It seems that `Observable.of` runs synchronously while `Rx.Observable.from(Promise.resolve('from1'))` runs asynchronously (that is what I want). As long as I want to test the spinner is displayed, the synchronous call is not an option for me.

There is some kind of solution when I e.g. delay it or set a timer:

```
Rx.Observable.of('of1').delay(0).subscribe...
```

but this also does not look good to me.

How can I turn `Observable.of` to run asynchronously? Converting it from Promise seems like an overkill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want an observable of to behave differently you can pass it a scheduler. You could use the async scheduler to make the observable emit values as soon as the call stack is clear. 
Code wise this would look like this:

```
Rx.Observable.of(1, 2, 3, Rx.Scheduler.async).subscribe(
    (val) => console.log(val)
);

console.log('first');
```

This will log out:

```
//first
//1
//2
//3
```

Working jsbin example here: http://jsbin.com/cunatiweqe/6/edit?js,console

Answer (score 3):

This is because observable.of has by default a null Scheduler. Check the official docs:

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-of

> By default, it uses a null IScheduler, which means the next
>   notifications are sent synchronously, although with a different
>   IScheduler it is possible to determine when those notifications will
>   be delivered.

So just import an async Scheduler

```
import { async } from 'rxjs/scheduler/async';
```

and send it as the second parameter

```
Observable.of('of1', async).subscribe(e => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 1):

The recent rxJS framework seems to favor `asyncScheduler` (import from `rxjs`) instead of `async` (`import from "rxjs/internal/scheduler/async"`). Example:

```
import { of asyncScheduler } from "rxjs";

const ret = of(this.someVariable, asyncScheduler);
```

More information about rxJS schedulers can be found [here](https://indepth.dev/rxjs-applying-asyncscheduler-as-an-argument-vs-with-observeon-operator/).