# Angular service testing: Cannot find name 'asyncData'

Tags: angular, testing

So I'm learning how to test services in Angular and I tried to copy the below example in the Angular docs.

```
let httpClientSpy: { get: jasmine.Spy };
let heroService: HeroService;

beforeEach(() => {
  // TODO: spy on other methods too
  httpClientSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['get']);
  heroService = new HeroService(<any> httpClientSpy);
});

it('should return expected heroes (HttpClient called once)', () => {
  const expectedHeroes: Hero[] =
    [{ id: 1, name: 'A' }, { id: 2, name: 'B' }];

  httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(asyncData(expectedHeroes));

  heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(
    heroes => expect(heroes).toEqual(expectedHeroes, 'expected heroes'),
    fail
  );
  expect(httpClientSpy.get.calls.count()).toBe(1, 'one call');
});
```

I tried to copy it quite literally, but it gives me the following error:

> ERROR in src/app/services/find-locals.service.spec.ts(17,38): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'asyncData'.

**Can someone help me with replacing this? Or telling me where I might have done something wrong elsewhere?**

**Here is the test file that copied from the Angular docs:**

```
import {FindLocalsService} from './find-locals.service';

import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

let findLocalsService: FindLocalsService;
let httpClientSpy: { get: jasmine.Spy, post: jasmine.Spy };

beforeEach(() => {
  httpClientSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['get', 'post']);
  findLocalsService = new FindLocalsService(<any> httpClientSpy, null);
});

it('should save location to server', function () {
  const expectedData: any =
    [{ id: 1, name: 'A' }, { id: 2, name: 'B' }];

  httpClientSpy.post.and.returnValue(asyncData(expectedData));

  findLocalsService.saveLocation('something').subscribe(
    data => expect(data).toEqual(expectedData),
          fail
  );

  expect(httpClientSpy.post.calls.count()).toBe(1, 'one call');
});
```

**Here is the service itself**

```
@Injectable()

export class FindLocalsService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authService: AuthenticationService){}

    saveLocation(locationObj){
        return this.http.post(url + '/findLocals/saveLocation', locationObj);
    }

    getThreeClosestPlayers() {
        const userId = this.authService.currentUser().user._id;
        console.log('entered 3 closest service', userId);

        return this.http.get(url + '/findLocals/getThreeClosestPlayers/' + userId)
            .pipe(
              map((data: any) => data.obj),
              catchError(this.handleError)
              )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Change this line:

```
httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(asyncData(expectedHeroes));
```

to use the Observable operator `of()`

```
httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(of(expectedHeroes));
```

This will return an observable that can be subscribed to and will return expectedHeroes.  If you are using Angular 6, you can import this directly from **rxjs**:

```
import {of} from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: Reading the tutorial docs, they claim `You can write many useful tests with this spy, even though its Observable is synchronous.` They include a blurb later on with this `asyncData` function that uses `defer` to be more asynchronous, so this might not be exactly equivalent even if it works mostly fine.

Comment: I am wondering why Angolar.io don't change its article from asyncData to Of ??? Its been hours that I am trying to review my code to fix this issue :|  Thanks man.

Comment: This is documented as wrong in the method itself

* THE FOLLOWING DON'T WORK
* Using `of().delay()` triggers TestBed errors;
* see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10127 .
*
* Using `asap` scheduler - as in `of(value, asap)` - doesn't work either.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/aio/content/examples/testing/src/testing/async-observable-helpers.ts

Answer (score 25):

I quote from: https://angular.io/guide/testing

*The async observable was produced by an `asyncData` helper. The `asyncData` helper is a utility function that you'll have to write yourself. Or you can copy this one from the sample code:*

**testing/async-observable-helpers.ts**

```
/** Create async observable that emits-once and completes
 *  after a JS engine turn */
export function asyncData<T>(data: T) {
  return defer(() => Promise.resolve(data));
}
```

Note: `defer` comes from `rxjs`, i.e.: `import { defer } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: Here's the link
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/aio/content/examples/testing/src/testing/async-observable-helpers.ts

Answer (score 2):

If download sample code from angular docs, you will find 'asyncData' definition in testing>async-observable-helpers.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

see [Observable.of turn async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529599/observable-of-turn-async)

```
Rx.Observable.of(1, 2, 3, Rx.Scheduler.async).subscribe(
    (val) => console.log(val)
);

console.log('first');
This will log out:

//first
//1
//2
//3
```

However, it's nice having `of()` synchronous by default. By just using `of` you get this order:

- expect1
- tap
- sub
- finalize
- expect2

example:

```
expect1()
of('hello').pipe(finalize(..),tap(..)).subscribe(..)
expect2()
```

if you make it async instead I think you will get this order:

- expect1
- expect2
- tap
- sub
- finalize

when i design a service method, i typically have it return an observable even if the component doesn't need any data from the service, I might return Observable using (map(() => null)). If I need to test code within that chain, I may create a helper method that can be called by the tests.