# How to test subscription to an Observable - when do I need done() and when must I provide the second parameter to subscribe?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I'm looking at the [Testing Services](https://angular.io/guide/testing-services) section of the Angular Guide, and I'm confused by some apparent inconsistencies on that page.

At the top, in the very first example it has a sample test like this:

```
it('#getObservableValue should return value from observable',
  (done: DoneFn) => {
  service.getObservableValue().subscribe(value => {
    expect(value).toBe('observable value');
    done();
  });
});
```

Notice that it calls `done()` at the end of the `subscribe` block.

Later on the same page there are some tests that use a different approach. For example, the very last example on the page has a test like this:

```
it('should return expected heroes (HttpClient called once)', () => {
  const expectedHeroes: Hero[] =
    [{ id: 1, name: 'A' }, { id: 2, name: 'B' }];

  httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(asyncData(expectedHeroes));

  heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(
    heroes => expect(heroes).toEqual(expectedHeroes, 'expected heroes'),
    fail
  );
  expect(httpClientSpy.get.calls.count()).toBe(1, 'one call');
});
```

The first thing that stands out is that this test does *not* call `done()`.

Secondly, it provides a second parameter (the `fail` function) to the `subscribe` call. (I do understand what that parameter is for). It actually calls out in the accompanying text that providing the second parameter is important:

> The subscribe() method takes a success (next) and fail (error) callback. Make sure you provide both callbacks so that you capture errors. Neglecting to do so produces an asynchronous uncaught observable error that the test runner will likely attribute to a completely different test.

...which begs the question(s):

1. Why does the second test not call `done()`, and
2. Why does the first test not provide the second parameter to `subscribe`?

I imagine that there is a "good reason" for both of these things, but it's not at all obvious to me what that is - and so it's difficult to know when to use which pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the documentation and I am confused as to what `asyncData` is. But I can understand your confusion and I will like to clarify what I do when I subscribe inside of unit tests.

I always call `done` at the end of the subscribe in a unit test to ensure it went through my assertions. I think `asyncData` returns `of` data and it makes `asynchronous` observable `synchronous`. You can read about it [here](https://netbasal.com/testing-observables-in-angular-a2dbbfaf5329).

1.) I think for the 2nd case, this is the case, where they have made the observable synchronous with `of` and they know that that `subscribe` block will be traversed "synchronously".

2.) `service.getObservableValue()` never fails so they don't need to provide the second parameter. They are confident that the observable will always run in the subscribe block and not the error block.

Basically, for the 2nd situation, they mock a success response and if it goes into the error block of the subscribe, we have a problem because we mocked a success response. Later on in the documentation, they mock an error response and called fail on the success block of the subscribe because it should not be ran.

To always be semantically correct when testing with observables:

```
it('should test the observable (success scenario)', (done: DoneFn) => {
  yourObservable$().subscribe(response => {
     expect(response).toBe('xyz');
     done(); // finished all my assertions
  }, fail); // if it goes to the error block, I have a bigger problem
});

it('should test the observable (error scenario)', (done: DoneFn) => {
  yourObservable$().subscribe(response => {
     fail(); // should not come here because we are mocking an error
  }, err => {
     expect(err).toBeTruthy();
     done(); // finished all my assertions  
  }); 
});
```

Of course adding all of that might make the code more chatty. As long as you're confident that the test does what it should do and every assertion is traversed, you should be okay.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense - though I do think the documentation should be clearer! According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52959047/98422) the asyncData makes the Observable **a**synchronous (which I assume is what you meant)  by using a deferred promise.